# Is there a rule of thumb for evaluating optimal time/memory complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I always have problems with evaluating a complexity of a problem. I usually try to find an O(n) solution but sometimes O(nlogn) or even O(n^2) is the best possible one.

One "rule of thumb" I know is that if you have a sorted array and you need to find something, it probably can be done in O(logn). Also I know that sorting can't be done quicker than O(nlogn). Are there any similar rules an unexperienced programmer can follow? Reoccurring problems you know the complexity of?

The most troublesome for me is the O(n^2), especially if I'm under pressure on an exam and I waste time on trying to find a better one.

I hope this isn't a too broad and opinion-based question.

Thanks!

Comment: See the Orders of Common Functions table here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_usages and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities

Answer (score 1):

Non comparison based sorting takes O(n) time. Eg: radix sort.

This seems like a good read. http://bigocheatsheet.com/ It contains list of common algorithms, their space and time complexity. Hope this helps.